# Searching for old release packages for Arm

Tags: package-management, libraries, arm64

I'm trying to locate some old packages for libswt-gtk-4-java & libswt-gtk-4-jni.

I have identified scattered across these sites:

http://archive.ubuntu.com

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com

all the old package release lists.

But where are the packages?

Also ARM64 packages appeared at Saucy located on (old-releases.ubuntu.com) but when looking at Trusty (archive.ubuntu.com) ARM64 packages have disappeared.

Anyway I have identified that I want the ARM64 versions (4.3.2-1) from Vivid.

Does anyone know where I can find these packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try download this packages using my Docker-based script named [deb-download](https://github.com/N0rbert/deb-download.git). You have to run it directly on ARM64.

Use commands below:

```
# setup the system
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker.io git
sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER

# reboot

# download my script
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/N0rbert/deb-download.git
cd deb-download
chmod +x deb-download.sh

# download packages
./deb-download.sh ubuntu vivid libswt-gtk-4-java libswt-gtk-4-jni
```

after running the script you can find the debs inside `~/Downloads/deb-download/storage` folder.

Another way is to grab deb-packages directly from https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/swt4-gtk/ .